# Will seeds effectively sprout after blending and leaving them in water?

Tags: blender, seeds, sprouting

Title is the question.

I'm most curious about the results with pumpkin seeds.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I can see no way in which it is related to food and/or cooking.

Comment: Letting seeds sprout is done in cooking sometimes in order to get flavor/texture changes, or sometimes to make them edible @LSchoon.

Comment: Does "blending" mean mixing several kinds of seeds together, or does it mean processing the seeds in a blender?

Comment: @ThePhoton the OP tagged it with "blender" and mentioned one type of especially interesting seeds, so I don't think they mean a mixture of different kinds.

Comment: @GdD Sure. The question mentions neither of those things, though.

Comment: @ThePhoton just the pumpkin seeds, I like to blend them, producing a milky texture.

Comment: Hi, the nutrition related content which you originally included in your question is off topic and very unwelcome on the site. As it is actually not relevant to the question, I decided to edit it out. Please don't revert to include it again, else we would have to delete the question outright.

Comment: Have you ever seen egg nog turn into a chicken?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It´s very likely that the blending will destroy the germ/embryo in the seed and also will separate it from the endosperm which delivers the required energy for the sprouting. So the seed will not sprout anymore when blended. But you could consider to let the seeds sprout first and then blend the sprouts.